# STM32 HAL stall in a loop

Tags: stm32

I'm just starting with STM32 devices and STM32Cube.
I made a simple blink code but the program get stuck in a forever loop in the HAL code.

```
__weak uint32_t HAL_GetTick(void)
{
  return uwTick;//<- Always performs this code in a loop after my code calls delay routine
}
```

My code is pretty simple and GPIO13 is set it as OUTPUT.
The Clk is external with PLL * 9 = 8MHz * 9 = 72MHz

```
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
 uint8_t x=0;
  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_13);
      x++;
      HAL_Delay(100);

    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the call stack of the Tick function? Is the systick counter working correctly and incrementing the uwTick variable?

Comment: which forever loop ?!

Comment: @A.R.C. No, but I think that maybe this function rely on some hardware timer that I didn't enable it. Could be?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean The loop is not in code like a for or while always keep running return uwTick; and never increments x again.